# Adding title and description to a Multipoint marker layer in Mapbox API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api, mapbox

I am using the following javascript to load pins of dealer locations on to a map. This is using the Mapbox API.

The <%=getDealerPins()%> method returns me a string formatted like "[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]...." etc. This seems to work quite well as my pins can change frequently.

What I need to know is, can I do the same thing for the title and description properties so I can give them their distinct names?

```
<link href='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='//api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.3.1/mapbox.js'></script>

<style>
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>

<div id='map' />

<script type='text/javascript'>

    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'guyh92.map-vt5qmr0v')

    L.mapbox.markerLayer({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
        type: 'MultiPoint',
        coordinates: [ <%=getDealerPins()%> ] 
    },
        properties: {
            title: ['Dealer'],
            description: ['1234'],
        }
    }).addTo(map);

    </script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each point has its own properties, you should use an array of [point](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#point) features rather than a single MultiPoint feature.